# Jruby rails, can't read certain DateTime value from mysql database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, jruby

I'm using rails 2.3.2 ,jruby 1.5.1, mysql 5.1 and activerecord-jdbcmysql-adapter-1.1.0.gem
.The problem is that: If there's a datetime column in the database table, and the column happened to have a value like 'xxxx-xx-xx 00:00:00', this value can't be read from rails.

Here's the console output:
[Console session screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dGt2r.png)

I set s.from to '2010-1-1 08:00:00', and I'm in timezone +8:00, so in database it's utc, and the value is '2010-1-1 00:00:00'. This value can't be read back from the database, but it is there in the database.

If the datetime string doesn't end with '00:00:00' in database, no problem happens.
I guess it's a bug of the activerecord-jdbcmysql-adapter gem, but I can't find a way to correct this, any advise?

Answer (score 1):

It certainly could be a bug in activerecord-jdbc. Can you phrase your question in the form of a testcase? Or file a bug in [JIRA](http://kenai.com/jira/browse/ACTIVERECORD_JDBC) or [Github](https://github.com/nicksieger/activerecord-jdbc-adapter/issues)?

Answer (score 1):

I came across the same issue. And I found that it was caused by a plugin [validates_date_time](https://github.com/nickstenning/validates_date_time) which overrides method [ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::Column.string_to_time](https://github.com/nickstenning/validates_date_time/blob/master/lib/parser.rb). This method can not parse time string without time portion like "2010-01-01" and returns a nil value because it assumes there must be a time portion (e.g. "2010-01-01 00:00:00")

However, In the JRuby JDBC Adapter, the time portion is discarded if it is all zeros, see function [timestampToRuby](https://github.com/jruby/activerecord-jdbc-adapter/blob/master/src/java/arjdbc/jdbc/RubyJdbcConnection.java):

```
protected IRubyObject timestampToRuby(Ruby runtime, ResultSet resultSet, Timestamp time)
        throws SQLException {
    if (time == null && resultSet.wasNull()) return runtime.getNil();

    String str = time.toString();
    if (str.endsWith(" 00:00:00.0")) {
        str = str.substring(0, str.length() - (" 00:00:00.0".length()));
    }
    if (str.endsWith(".0")) {
        str = str.substring(0, str.length() - (".0".length()));
    }

    return RubyString.newUnicodeString(runtime, str);
}
```

That is why ActiveRecord returned nil for this attribute.

To fix this, you could fix the above issue in the validates_date_time plugin or replace it with another date time validator.